# How to create a Dockerfile to install Eclipse IDE and configure GUI for the following specifications?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I have been assigned a project with following specifications and I will just need to install Eclipse IDE I am not going to work on it.

Specifications for Dockerfile are:

1. Use base OS as Ubuntu and install utilities like git, vim, build-essential etc.
2. Install and configure openJDK. Take care to set environmental variables.
3. Install Eclipse IDE and configure GUI accordingly.
4. Install and configure Apache Tomcat.
5. Expose default port 8080,80.

I have created docker file according to the above specifications but I don't know the syntax for installing Eclipse IDE and configuring GUI accordingly.

```
#Base OS
FROM ubuntu

#Install utilites
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install apt-utils && \
    apt-get -y install vim && \
    apt-get -y install git;

#Install OpenJDK-8
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk && \
    apt-get install -y ant && \
    apt-get clean;

#Setup JAVA_HOME -- env. variables
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
RUN export JAVA_HOME

#Set up Eclipse IDE


#Install and Ccnfigure Apache Tomcat
RUN mkdir /usr/local/tomcat
RUN wget http://www-us.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.16/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.16.tar.gz -O /tmp/tomcat.tar.gz
RUN cd /tmp && tar xvfz tomcat.tar.gz
RUN cp -Rv /tmp/apache-tomcat-8.5.16/* /usr/local/tomcat/
EXPOSE 8080
CMD /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh run
```

Comment: What attempt have you made at completing this task?

Comment: I'd recommend taking a look at some [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/) documentation. I would also take another look at the use cases for containerization as I am not familiar with containers being used to establish GUI-based development environments.

Comment: are you going to use some tools like remote desktop or X2Go to connect to your dockrerized ubuntu GUI or Eclipse has some remote connect/gui capability? In such way you will need to expose more ports and install Eclipse the same way as on any Ubuntu,. If I remember correctly  you can just unpack it in the directory and run.

Comment: I have to create project and I will just need to install Eclipse IDE. I am not going to work on it.